# AWS VPN Client Failed to Work

Tags: amazon-web-services, mac-osx, vpn-client

AWS Client VPN use to work until today. It stop working with the following
**-AWS VPN Client Helper Tool is required to establish the connection.-**
I've tried reinstalling the Client found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn-download/) and it still didnt resolve the issue.
I tried to uninstall and i get the same error.

I've restart the mac(M1) multiple times, Reinstall The Monterray OS(didn't removed all applications** don't know why).

I've tried checking the logs and found the following.

```
❯ tail -f /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/logs/aws_vpn_client_20221018.log
2022-10-18 15:36:27.254 +02:00 [DBG] Helper app --init output: Helper failed to install.
2022-10-18 15:36:27.254 +02:00 [DBG] Helper failed to install or was canceled.
2022-10-18 15:36:27.254 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:36:27.254 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
2022-10-18 15:36:27.255 +02:00 [DBG] Metric agent started
2022-10-18 15:36:27.255 +02:00 [DBG] Received exception for connection state Disconnected. Show error message to user
2022-10-18 15:36:27.255 +02:00 [ERR] Exception recieved by connection view controller
ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.HelperToolInstallationFailedException: AWS VPN Client Helper Tool is required to establish the connection.
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnOsxProcessManager.Start (System.String openVpnConfigPath, System.String managementPortPasswordFile, System.Int32 timeoutMilliseconds) [0x001f6] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.Connect (ACVC.Core.Metadata.OvpnConnectionProfile configProfile, ACVC.Core.GetCredentialsCallback getCredentialsCallback, System.Int32 timeout) [0x0020f] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
2022-10-18 15:40:00.882 +02:00 [DBG] Clean up connections. Connection state: Connecting
2022-10-18 15:40:00.884 +02:00 [INF] Validating schema for OpenVPN config: /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/test-eu
2022-10-18 15:40:01.889 +02:00 [DBG] Caught exception when getting connection status. Exception information: System.TimeoutException: The message did not respond within the expected timeframe or was cancelled
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.SendMessage (System.String message, System.Int32 timeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ca] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.GetConnectionStatus () [0x0007c] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.Metrics.MetricsClient.RecordBytesMetricsAndAnalytics (ACVC.Core.IConnectionManager connectionManager) [0x00077] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
2022-10-18 15:40:01.890 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:40:01.890 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
2022-10-18 15:40:01.892 +02:00 [INF] Terminating connection
2022-10-18 15:40:01.892 +02:00 [WRN] Acs did not stop correctly!
2022-10-18 15:40:01.892 +02:00 [DBG]  Ending connection details reporting.
2022-10-18 15:40:01.892 +02:00 [WRN] We are calling GracefulKill in a method that is not supposed to change Connection state.
2022-10-18 15:40:01.892 +02:00 [DBG] GracefulKill
2022-10-18 15:40:01.893 +02:00 [DBG] Cancelling socket listen token
2022-10-18 15:40:01.893 +02:00 [DBG] Dispose socket
2022-10-18 15:40:01.893 +02:00 [DBG] Signal process kill with helper tool.
2022-10-18 15:40:01.893 +02:00 [DBG] Starting process
2022-10-18 15:40:01.926 +02:00 [DBG] Start to read process output
2022-10-18 15:40:01.962 +02:00 [DBG] End reading process output
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Helper app --kill output: Kill success.
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Release process manager start lock
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Release process manager stop lock
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Disconnected
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:40:02.028 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
2022-10-18 15:40:06.195 +02:00 [INF] Saving profile store to /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/ConnectionProfiles
2022-10-18 15:40:06.197 +02:00 [INF] Connecting /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/test-eu
2022-10-18 15:40:06.198 +02:00 [DBG] validationString: /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/test-eu
1666100416
2022-10-18 15:40:06.198 +02:00 [DBG] Shutting down metrics agent
2022-10-18 15:40:06.198 +02:00 [DBG] Metrics agent shut down
2022-10-18 15:40:06.354 +02:00 [INF] Starting OpenVpn process
2022-10-18 15:40:06.354 +02:00 [DBG] Starting process
2022-10-18 15:40:06.375 +02:00 [DBG] Start to read process output
2022-10-18 15:40:10.553 +02:00 [DBG] End reading process output
2022-10-18 15:40:10.617 +02:00 [DBG] Helper app --init output: Helper failed to install.
2022-10-18 15:40:10.617 +02:00 [DBG] Helper failed to install or was canceled.
2022-10-18 15:40:10.617 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:40:10.617 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
2022-10-18 15:40:10.618 +02:00 [DBG] Metric agent started
2022-10-18 15:40:10.618 +02:00 [DBG] Received exception for connection state Disconnected. Show error message to user
2022-10-18 15:40:10.618 +02:00 [ERR] Exception recieved by connection view controller
ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.HelperToolInstallationFailedException: AWS VPN Client Helper Tool is required to establish the connection.
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnOsxProcessManager.Start (System.String openVpnConfigPath, System.String managementPortPasswordFile, System.Int32 timeoutMilliseconds) [0x001f6] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.Connect (ACVC.Core.Metadata.OvpnConnectionProfile configProfile, ACVC.Core.GetCredentialsCallback getCredentialsCallback, System.Int32 timeout) [0x0020f] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
2022-10-18 15:40:11.802 +02:00 [DBG] Clean up connections. Connection state: Connecting
2022-10-18 15:40:11.803 +02:00 [INF] Validating schema for OpenVPN config: /Users/saviourgidi/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/test-eu
2022-10-18 15:40:12.806 +02:00 [DBG] Caught exception when getting connection status. Exception information: System.TimeoutException: The message did not respond within the expected timeframe or was cancelled
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.SendMessage (System.String message, System.Int32 timeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ca] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.GetConnectionStatus () [0x0007c] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
  at ACVC.Core.Metrics.MetricsClient.RecordBytesMetricsAndAnalytics (ACVC.Core.IConnectionManager connectionManager) [0x00077] in <122123b2b3914e32b2c06bd2a2d00f27>:0
2022-10-18 15:40:12.807 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:40:12.807 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
2022-10-18 15:40:12.809 +02:00 [INF] Terminating connection
2022-10-18 15:40:12.809 +02:00 [WRN] Acs did not stop correctly!
2022-10-18 15:40:12.809 +02:00 [DBG]  Ending connection details reporting.
2022-10-18 15:40:12.809 +02:00 [WRN] We are calling GracefulKill in a method that is not supposed to change Connection state.
2022-10-18 15:40:12.809 +02:00 [DBG] GracefulKill
2022-10-18 15:40:12.810 +02:00 [DBG] Cancelling socket listen token
2022-10-18 15:40:12.810 +02:00 [DBG] Dispose socket
2022-10-18 15:40:12.810 +02:00 [DBG] Signal process kill with helper tool.
2022-10-18 15:40:12.810 +02:00 [DBG] Starting process
2022-10-18 15:40:12.842 +02:00 [DBG] Start to read process output
2022-10-18 15:40:12.875 +02:00 [DBG] End reading process output
2022-10-18 15:40:12.943 +02:00 [DBG] Helper app --kill output: Kill success.
2022-10-18 15:40:12.944 +02:00 [DBG] Release process manager start lock
2022-10-18 15:40:12.944 +02:00 [DBG] Release process manager stop lock
2022-10-18 15:40:12.944 +02:00 [DBG] Disconnected
2022-10-18 15:40:12.944 +02:00 [DBG] Stopping DNS monitoring thread
2022-10-18 15:40:12.944 +02:00 [DBG] Releasing DNS monitoring lock
```

Answer (score 3):

I just spent about 25 hours trying to debug this, basically in tears. Finally pieced it together so I'm posting the solution here

You have to run

```
sudo launchctl enable system/com.amazonaws.acvc.helper
```

To allow the helper to install. Make sure you are in the PrivilegedHelperTools folder when you run this

Comment: I had to reinstall the Whole OS. Poor me!